# J to print out status bar and percentage

Tags: j

I am calculating the processing time by putting

```
start =: 6!:0 ''
```

at the top of my code and putting

```
end =: (6!:0 '') - start
```

at the end of my code. However, is there any way that I can implement a status bar like this in J?

```
[====                      ]  25%
[============              ]  50%
[==========================] 100%
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use `smoutput` defined as `0 0 $ 1!:2&2` by the system to display your processing milestones on the screen

```
someverb =: 3 : 0
   smoutput '{        }'
   code
   smoutput '{+++     }'
   more code
   smoutput '{+++++   }'
   more code
   smoutput '{++++++++}'
)
```

but you would have to know that the places that you insert the smoutput expressions would correspond to the amount of processing that had taken place.

As an example:

```
   test =: 3 : 0
​smoutput 6!:0 'hh:mm:ss.sss'
​6!:3 (2) NB. 2 second delay
​smoutput 6!:0 'hh:mm:ss.sss'
​6!:3 (2) NB. 2 second delay
​smoutput 6!:0 'hh:mm:ss.sss'
​)
   test ''
14:53:42.313
14:53:44.317 NB. after two second delay
14:53:46.326 NB. after two second delay
```

or closer to the output you would like

```
test1 =: 3 : 0
  start=. 6!:0 ''
  smoutput '[            ]   0%'
  6!:3 (2) NB. 2 second delay
  smoutput '[===         ]  25%'
  6!:3 (2) NB. 2 second delay
  smoutput '[======      ]  50%'
  6!:3 (4) NB. 4 second delay
  smoutput '[============] 100%'
  (6!:0 '')- start
)
   test1 ''
[            ]   0%
[===         ]  25%
[======      ]  50%
[============] 100%
0 0 0 0 0 8.01821
```